# sudden error on sharelatex

Tags: floats, errors

[image]

[image]

i'm user of sharelatex on making pdf file. 
actually i got terrible error on inserting figure (image).
it was fine around yesterday, but as i checked this file today, this system only recognize scale of figure, it doesn't capture figure itself.

also, when text is long enough to get off one row, it just show up black small blocks on it. it is also the thing which appeared today.

```
 \begin{figure}[h] \centering 
 \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{fig12_1.png} 
 \caption{ $y = \ln x$의 Variational Transform}
 \label{fig:12-1}
 \end{figure}
```

i didn't change anything beyond tex file. why is it making this kind of error?
thank you.

Comment: Remove `draft` from `\documentclass[...]{...}`

Comment: does draft mean things like {oblivoir}?

Comment: do you have `\documentclass[draft]{oblivoir}` or `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}` ? The output you show is the standard "draft mode" display so either something specified `draft` or there should be a error in the log saying it could not find the image

Comment: the black box at the end of the line is an indication that the content of that line is wider than `\textwidth`.  in the case you show, it's so small that it most likely won't be noticed (especially since it is a hyphen, which has a very small presence).  there will be an "overfull hbox" report in your log saying how wide the overage is.  the black box (like the "empty except for name" figure) will disappear when the `[draft]` option is removed.